# Por que o comando “rails new” não está criando o esqueleto MVC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Olá,

Estou tendo um problema com o Rails, quando eu executo o comando `rails new nome_do_projeto` no terminal ele deveria criar o esqueleto de pasta *MVC* e os arquivos contendo as dependências porém o comando só cria os arquivos.

Alguém sabe como posso fazer com que o comando crie também as pastas necessárias?

No terminal fica assim:

```
rails new nome_do_projeto
    create
    create  README.md
    create  Rakefile
    create  .ruby-version
    create  config.ru
    create  .gitignore
    create  Gemfile
      run  git init from "."
```

Como mostrado no código acima, o comando rails new nome_do_projeto cria apenas os arquivos necessários mas não cria as pastas do esqueleto MVC, por exemplo a pasta **app, bin, config** entre outras.

Estas são as versões que estão em minha máquina:

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x64-mingw32]

gem -v
3.1.2

rails -v
Rails 6.0.2.1
```

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema reinstalando o Git no mesmo disco que o ruby